# How to Execute Python Script as Administrator in SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `Python (3.7.2)` file that pulls data from a third party `API`, saves the data in a local `CSV` file on `Windows Server 2016` and then does a `bulk import` into an instance of `SQL Server 2016` (13.0.4224.16).

This works without issue if I manually run the script from an elevated command prompt. However, I don't want to have to manually run this script as I'm wanting it to execute every hour. I know how to schedule from the `Task Scheduler` on the server OS, but I would like to schedule as an automated job using `SQL Server Agent`. This way I can directly manage/track the jobs with `SSMS` and not have to log in to the server itself to check the scheduled tasks.

I currently have a job configured with 1 step of type `Operating system (CmdExec)` and the `Command:` set to `"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" "python C:\PythonScripts\myPython.py"`:

[image]

My thinking with the above is that `cmd.exe` would be opened and call the `python.exe` program with the python path I supplied.

However, when I run the job it just hangs in status of `In progress` and never finishes. The script when run manually successfully completes in 9 seconds:

[image]

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem to my question by adding a credential/[proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-sql-server-agent-proxy?view=sql-server-ver15) account, assigning it to the `Run as` in the step, and then altering the `Command` to look like this:

`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C python "C:\PythonScripts\myPython.py"`

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on the credential/proxy account bit and `Run as` part?

Comment: How did you configured the proxy?

Comment: @LucasSousa did you find out the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using sp_execute_external_script ?

```
execute sp_execute_external_script 
@language = N'Python', 
@script = N'
a = 1
b = 2
c = a/b
d = a*b
print(c, d)
'
```

For example, this code can be scheduled into SqlAgent.

Comment: Yes, I saw `sp_execute_external_script` but unless there's a way to directly reference a `.py` file this just seems like a band-aid solution. I would rather not embed 100+ lines of Python into a job. Seems much more intuitive to just call the script that already exists on the server.