# Call Python file from within SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server

I have Python script in a file names **"C:\Python\HL.py"**

In this Python script there are predictive models and updates to some tables in my SQL database.

I want to call this file as a SQL Job

How can I achieve that?

This question is different

[How to Execute Python Script as Administrator in SQL Server Agent Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54680105/how-to-execute-python-script-as-administrator-in-sql-server-agent-job)

the provided solutions were through proxy command and scripting in the SQL.

I just want to call a Python .py file from within SQL Server Job

Comment: refer to documentation on SQL Agent https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Squirrel there is nothing about python there!

Comment: execute it as Subsystems `Operating System` command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Execute Python Script as Administrator in SQL Server Agent Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54680105/how-to-execute-python-script-as-administrator-in-sql-server-agent-job)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you creating a SQL Server Agent job step, you should select:
1. Step type: **Operating system (CmdExec)**
2. Run as: here you can use Agent service account (less secure) or better option is to create dedicated service account and register it as a proxy account. If you decide to use Agent service account, you will be granting Server Admin privileges to python scripts.
3. In command type: **"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" "python C:\Python\HL.py"**

Answer (score 2):

Create a job step with this script

```
DECLARE @CMDSQL VARCHAR(1000)


SET @CMDSQL = 'cmd.exe py "C:\Python\HL.py" '
Exec master..xp_cmdshell @CMDSQL
```

[image]

But make sure your xp_cmdshell is enabled.

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', '1'
RECONFIGURE
-- this enables xp_cmdshell
sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', '1' 
RECONFIGURE
```

Comment: Using SQL Agent step is correct, but I disagree with using SQL Server service account, step type "TSQL" and xp_cmdshell.

Comment: I did that but I only got this : Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
NULL
C:\Windows\system32>

Comment: have you set your python path?