# How to execute python '.py' file in SQL Server machine learning services?

Tags: python, sql-server, machine-learning

I'm trying to call .py file in SQL ML Services and put it into the @script variable. This issue differs from '[Call Python file from within SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58160480/call-python-file-from-within-sql-server)' question as I do not want it to be put into SQL job.

I need sth like:

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script @language = N'Python', 
  @script = (read from python file .py)
```

The point is NOT to use any python code in the SQL scripts and reference it to the .py file for maintainability purposes.

Comment: *"I do not want it to be put into SQL job"* you don't have to. What is the problem here? What do you mean you need "sth"? What is "sth"? Have you had a read of the documentation? [Quickstart: Run simple Python scripts with SQL machine learning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/tutorials/quickstart-python-create-script?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Yes, I have read it. I need to set script parameter to an external python .py file like 
@script = refer to script.py

Comment: Use `OPENROWSET` to read the file and store it into a variable.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu It worked!