# Import requests ModuleNotFoundError: No module names 'requests'

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, request, python-requests, sql-server-agent

I want to schedule a python script in SQL Server and I have followed this [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54680105/how-to-execute-python-script-as-administrator-in-sql-server-agent-job) and it's solution in the answers

When I run the job it fails and throws this error:

> import request ModeulNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

[image]

I tried pip install requests and many other things found on StackOverflow but I just can't seem to figure this out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just added all the libraries I was using into my python file directory and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to create a previous task running "pip install requests".

Comment: You might want to explain how that can be done, in order to get closer to [answer].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).